# Generate proper report when data is not in database [Telerik]

Tags: sql, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I'm generating telerik report for 
"Number of students by level of education, field and sex"

Here the SQL query that I'm using to create this report

```
SELECT
    [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_ID], 
    [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_Level], 
    [tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID] AS 'tbl_hec_ProgrammeISCED_ID', 
    [tbl_hec_Programme].[Programme_ID], 
    [tbl_hec_Programme].[Specialisation_ID_Number], 
    [tbl_hec_specialisation].[Rank_ID_Number], 
    [tbl_hec_specialisation].[Rank_Title], 
    [tbl_HEI_student].[Programme_ID] AS 'tbl_HEI_studentProgramme_ID', 
    [tbl_HEI_student].[Gender]
FROM ((([tbl_HEI_student]
 FULL OUTER JOIN [tbl_hec_Programme]
 ON [tbl_HEI_student].[Programme_ID] = [tbl_hec_Programme].[Programme_ID])
 FULL OUTER JOIN [tbl_hec_specialisation]
 ON [tbl_hec_Programme].[Specialisation_ID_Number] = [tbl_hec_specialisation].[Rank_ID_Number])
 FULL OUTER JOIN [tbl_hec_ISCED]
 ON [tbl_hec_Programme].[ISCED_ID] = [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_ID])
WHERE ([tbl_HEI_student].[Gender]='Male' or [tbl_HEI_student].[Gender]='Female') and ([tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_Level]='5' or [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_Level]='6'or [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_Level]='7'or [tbl_hec_ISCED].[ISCED_Level]='8')
```

I'm getting null report since some values are not in database. I attached picture of it ,

HERE that view

[image]

I want generate report when there is no data in database. like below which means zero values for null rows.

HERE the expected report output

[image]

How can I overcome this challenge

Comment: For this kind of report, I think it's easier to use a template document with placeholders and then set them with the calculated values from code. Will this be applicable to you? I can provide some example code if needed.

Comment: Yes please , can you mention it here as an answer ,I'll try to integrate ,

Comment: how did you go with this? It's been a year. If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted answer. Or at least put comments or upvote it so it can help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use document merging functionality using a template with all the report layout already set up as well as value placeholders (fields) that will be replaced by calculated values.

I'm using Aspose.Words library in my projects, but I'm sure there are others out there maybe even Telerik Reporting. This is very simple functionality so any reporting tool that can do complex stuff must be able to do this as well.

Here's some example code for Aspose. Other libraries will have different implementation.

```
using Aspose.Words;

void GenerateDocument(string templateFilePath, Dictionary<string, object> fieldNamesAndValues) 
{
    // This is our document object
    Document output = null;

    // Obtain the template file
    if (File.Exists(templateFilePath))
    {
        // If the template file is successfully located, use this template
        output = new Document(templateFilePath);
    }

    // Merge the provided values into the appropriate fields of the template
    output.MailMerge.Execute(fieldNamesAndValues.Keys.ToArray(), fieldNamesAndValues.Values.ToArray());

    // Save the document into a stream as PDF
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    doc.Save(stream, SaveFormat.Pdf);

    // You can then do whatever with the stream: 
    // save it or push it to the browser for download
}
```

Using your expected result as an example, let's assume these are the names of your placeholders (fields) for the first row:

```
MALE_EDUCATION_ISCED5, MALE_EDUCATION_ISCED6, MALE_EDUCATION_ISCED7
```

You can then generate your report like so:

```
Dictionary<string, object> fieldsAndValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

fieldsAndValues.Add("MALE_EDUCATION_ISCED5", calculatedValue1);
fieldsAndValues.Add("MALE_EDUCATION_ISCED6", calculatedValue2);
fieldsAndValues.Add("MALE_EDUCATION_ISCED7", calculatedValue3);
// and so on for other fields

GenerateDocument("~/Templates/Report.docx", fieldsAndValues);
```

More info on how to add fields in Microsoft Word:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/7e9ea3b4-83ec-4203-9e66-4efc027f2cf3

More info on Aspose MailMerge:
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Execute+Simple+Mail+Merge